# May the qemu running just a program not need a full system?

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu

I'm doing some tests but I'd had some problems using WINE as tool. I used to use qemu to make my test but running a clomplet sistem. But what I need now is just run a ordinary program. What I want know if is possible use qemu to just run a singular program, like wine, without need a full system. If yes, is there any example that can show me?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `qemu` in "User-mode emulation" to run programs compiled for a different CPU architecture (e.g. run PowerPC code on X86), these still need to be Linux programs using the Linux API.

This can't be used to run programs with a completely different API, e.g. Win32. For Windows programs to run, you either need to offer a rewrite of the Windows API (i.e. WINE) or you need to run Windows, which requires a full system virtualization. `qemu` principally can't offer anything in that regard.

To run Linux software in a more lightweight fashion then full system virtualization, things like Docker exist.